# How to use matrices to set constraints in Julia?

Tags: for-loop, matrix, constraints, julia, julia-jump

I am trying to write a linear optimization  model in Julia. I have several constraints to add, and I wanted to try and set them using matrices instead of setting each one manually. I have upwards of 5 constraints but I narrowed it down to two just to try and get the code to work. Here is the code I have so far:

```
m = Model()
@defVar(m, x[1:2] >= 0)
c= [8 12]
@setObjective(m, Max, sum([c[i]*x[i] for i= 1:2]))
A=[6 8 ; 10 20]
B= [72 140]' #bounds
for j=1:2
    @setConstraint(m,sum([A[j,i]*x[i] for i=1:2])<=B[j])
end
```

When I run this code, the `@setObjective` function works but the @setConstraints function keeps coming up with the error `@setConstraint not defined` .
Does anyone know how to fix this or does anyone know a better way to write this using matrices or another shorter way?

Comment: i think that should be `@addConstraint` :D

Comment: yes! got the command wrong thank you for the quick catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `@addConstraint` (not `@setConstraint` ) and then it works